# Number of total orders for a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have noticed in passing that the number of total orders on a set of $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ is $n!$ I also know ( and actually know why) the total number of bijections from a finite set of n elements to itself is $n!$ random chance doesn't really happen in mathematics; so my question is correlation and why?

Comment: Think about it.  Imagine you list all the elements of the set in a list from least to greatest.  Every ordering will make such a list and each different order will make a different list, and every possible list could define an order.   So there are as many orders as there are lists.  How many lists are there?