# Number of distinct total orders on a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

This is from a class question, not looking for someone to do homework for me, just seeking clarification.

**Let the set X=(a,b,c)**

**How many distinct total orders can be defined on this set? Why?**

I did search around a bit and from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223502/number-of-total-orders-for-a-relation), someone said that for a set of N elements the number of total orders is N!

My question is: is this correct, and why? My class notes define a "total order" as a partial order which is comparable, with a partial order being a relation that is Reflexive, Transititve and Antisymmetric. I get all that, but I'm confused as to how this relates to the question given.

Comment: It's just like the number of ways that we can arrange $N$ elements in a row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $N!$ is correct.

Note that for your set {a,b,c} we get  $$\{a<b<c, a<c<b, b<a<c, b<c<a, c<a<b, c<b<a\}$$

Thus these are just the arrangements with  order which is permutations and the number of permutations on $N$ is $N!$